# Take image from SD card, compress it, and save it back to SD?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Im trying to capture an image from the camera, and if its too big i want to compress the bitmap and send it back to the sd card. I initially tried to pull the image directly into internal memory but apparently according to this answer to my previous question i can do that: [android picture from camera being taken at a really small size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322260/android-picture-from-camera-being-taken-at-a-really-small-size)

How could I bring that image file back into my apps internal memory?

Answer (score 0):

You may rescale image using the code below.

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

This will compress your image to smaller size, you just have need to give new height and width as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Onclick of button Call Method to Save your Image to SDcard:**

```
SaveImage(bitmap);
```

**Saving Image to SdCard:**

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File myDir = new File(root + "/demo_images");    
  myDir.mkdirs();
  Random generator = new Random();
  int n = 10000;
  n = generator.nextInt(n);
  fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
  File file = new File (myDir, fname);
// Below code will give you full path in TextView

> txtPath1.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

  if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
  try {
         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
         finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
         out.flush();
         out.close();

  } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**For getting Image from SdCard:**

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
imageview.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```

**For Storing Image to Internal Memory:**

[Saving and Reading Bitmaps/Images from Internal memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-images-to-internal-memory-in-android)

Answer (score -2):

The image that you get from the camera is already compressed in the jpeg format. You will never get a raw image from the camera.