# How to set an image in assets folder from Url in android

Tags: android, image, load, directory, assets

I am planning to show some image in my app. Also, this images must be in assets folder. First I will upload images into assets folder from url, and when app runs, must show this images from assets folder. Is there any possible way to do this ?

Comment: "this images must be in assets folder" -- why? "I will upload images into assets folder from url" -- assets are read-only at runtime. Is this "upload" process something that you are doing as part of your development process?

Comment: Yes. Upload is my process. The app read images from assets folder. And how can I show my images that I get this from url ?

Answer (score 0):

The assets folder is read-only the images you get should be saved to a spot on the device then referenced by its path

Answer (score 0):

there is a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674787/4774515) for how to save image to internal directory and load them