# How to save the current image from viewpager?

Tags: android

I have images in a `ViewPager` and I want user to can save the current image by click on a button to save the image to sd card in phone

This is my demoactivity.java

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
Button play;
MediaPlayer mp;

public int playstop = 0;

private Button extisaw;
public void onCreate(Bundle ww) {
    super.onCreate(ww);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saw);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raj);
    show1();
    show2();
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (playstop == 0) {
                    MediaHandler(mp, 1);
                    mp.start();
                    playstop = 1;

                } else {
                    MediaHandler(mp, 2);
                    mp.pause();
                    playstop = 0;
                }
            }
        });
}

private void show2()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method

    this.extisaw =
        (Button)this.findViewById
    (R.id.about);
    this.extisaw.setOnClickListener
    (new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
    });}

public void MediaHandler
(MediaPlayer mp, int e) {
    if (e == 1) {
        mp.start();
    } else {
        mp.pause();
    }
}

public void show1() {
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[]{
        R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2,
        R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4,
        R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6,
        R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8
        , R.drawable.a9, R.drawable.a10, R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12
        , R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a14, R.drawable.a15
        , R.drawable.a16, R.drawable.a17, R.drawable.a18, R.drawable.a19
        , R.drawable.a20, R.drawable.a21, R.drawable.a22, R.drawable.a23
        ,
        R.drawable.a24, R.drawable.a25,
        R.drawable.a26, R.drawable.a27
        , R.drawable.a29,
        R.drawable.a30, R.drawable.a31
        , R.drawable.a32, R.drawable.a33, R.drawable.a34, R.drawable.a35
        , R.drawable.a36, R.drawable.a37, R.drawable.a38
        , R.drawable.a39, R.drawable.a40, R.drawable.a42
        , R.drawable.a43, R.drawable.a44, R.drawable.a45, R.drawable.a46,
        R.drawable.a47, R.drawable.a48,
        R.drawable.a49
        , R.drawable.a51,
        R.drawable.a52, R.drawable.a53
        , R.drawable.a54, R.drawable.a55, R.drawable.a56
        , R.drawable.a58, R.drawable.a59, R.drawable.a60
        , R.drawable.a61, R.drawable.a62, R.drawable.a63
        , R.drawable.a64, R.drawable.a65, R.drawable.a66, R.drawable.a67, R.drawable.a68, R.drawable.a69


        , R.drawable.a70,
        R.drawable.a71, R.drawable.a72
        , R.drawable.a73, R.drawable.a74, R.drawable.a75
        , R.drawable.a76, R.drawable.a77, R.drawable.a78
        , R.drawable.a79, R.drawable.a80, R.drawable.a81
        , R.drawable.a82, R.drawable.a83, R.drawable.a84, R.drawable.a85, R.drawable.a86, R.drawable.a87

        , R.drawable.a88,
        R.drawable.a89, R.drawable.a90
        , R.drawable.a91, R.drawable.a93
        , R.drawable.a94, R.drawable.a95, R.drawable.a96
        , R.drawable.a97, R.drawable.a98, R.drawable.a99

    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = DemoActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how ru showing the images , i,e which lib ru using for displaying the images.

Comment: can you post your code..

Comment: I have post my code see it

Answer (score 1):

This is my code
 There is 2 button
Play and stop music
And exit button and all work good
But I want to add a button for user to can save the current image of view pager to the phone memory

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
Button play;
MediaPlayer mp;

public int playstop = 0;

private Button extisaw;
public void onCreate(Bundle ww) {
    super.onCreate(ww);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saw);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raj);
    show1();
    show2();
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (playstop == 0) {
                    MediaHandler(mp, 1);
                    mp.start();
                    playstop = 1;

                } else {
                    MediaHandler(mp, 2);
                    mp.pause();
                    playstop = 0;
                }
            }
        });
}

private void show2()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method

    this.extisaw =
        (Button)this.findViewById
    (R.id.about);
    this.extisaw.setOnClickListener
    (new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
    });}

public void MediaHandler
(MediaPlayer mp, int e) {
    if (e == 1) {
        mp.start();
    } else {
        mp.pause();
    }
}

public void show1() {
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[]{
        R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2,
        R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4,
        R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6,
        R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8
        , R.drawable.a9, R.drawable.a10, R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12
        , R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a14, R.drawable.a15
        , R.drawable.a16, R.drawable.a17, R.drawable.a18, R.drawable.a19
        , R.drawable.a20, R.drawable.a21, R.drawable.a22, R.drawable.a23
        ,
        R.drawable.a24, R.drawable.a25,
        R.drawable.a26, R.drawable.a27
        , R.drawable.a29,
        R.drawable.a30, R.drawable.a31
        , R.drawable.a32, R.drawable.a33, R.drawable.a34, R.drawable.a35
        , R.drawable.a36, R.drawable.a37, R.drawable.a38
        , R.drawable.a39, R.drawable.a40, R.drawable.a42
        , R.drawable.a43, R.drawable.a44, R.drawable.a45, R.drawable.a46,
        R.drawable.a47, R.drawable.a48,
        R.drawable.a49
        , R.drawable.a51,
        R.drawable.a52, R.drawable.a53
        , R.drawable.a54, R.drawable.a55, R.drawable.a56
        , R.drawable.a58, R.drawable.a59, R.drawable.a60
        , R.drawable.a61, R.drawable.a62, R.drawable.a63
        , R.drawable.a64, R.drawable.a65, R.drawable.a66, R.drawable.a67, R.drawable.a68, R.drawable.a69


        , R.drawable.a70,
        R.drawable.a71, R.drawable.a72
        , R.drawable.a73, R.drawable.a74, R.drawable.a75
        , R.drawable.a76, R.drawable.a77, R.drawable.a78
        , R.drawable.a79, R.drawable.a80, R.drawable.a81
        , R.drawable.a82, R.drawable.a83, R.drawable.a84, R.drawable.a85, R.drawable.a86, R.drawable.a87

        , R.drawable.a88,
        R.drawable.a89, R.drawable.a90
        , R.drawable.a91, R.drawable.a93
        , R.drawable.a94, R.drawable.a95, R.drawable.a96
        , R.drawable.a97, R.drawable.a98, R.drawable.a99

    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = DemoActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-images-to-internal-memory-in-android

Answer (score 1):

i add my code to your activity class now try this..

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
Button play;
MediaPlayer mp;
private int[] mImages = new int[]{
        R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2,
        R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4,
        R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6,
        R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8
        , R.drawable.a9, R.drawable.a10, R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12
        , R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a14, R.drawable.a15
        , R.drawable.a16, R.drawable.a17, R.drawable.a18, R.drawable.a19
        , R.drawable.a20, R.drawable.a21, R.drawable.a22, R.drawable.a23
        ,
        R.drawable.a24, R.drawable.a25,
        R.drawable.a26, R.drawable.a27
        , R.drawable.a29,
        R.drawable.a30, R.drawable.a31
        , R.drawable.a32, R.drawable.a33, R.drawable.a34, R.drawable.a35
        , R.drawable.a36, R.drawable.a37, R.drawable.a38
        , R.drawable.a39, R.drawable.a40, R.drawable.a42
        , R.drawable.a43, R.drawable.a44, R.drawable.a45, R.drawable.a46,
        R.drawable.a47, R.drawable.a48,
        R.drawable.a49
        , R.drawable.a51,
        R.drawable.a52, R.drawable.a53
        , R.drawable.a54, R.drawable.a55, R.drawable.a56
        , R.drawable.a58, R.drawable.a59, R.drawable.a60
        , R.drawable.a61, R.drawable.a62, R.drawable.a63
        , R.drawable.a64, R.drawable.a65, R.drawable.a66, R.drawable.a67, R.drawable.a68, R.drawable.a69


        , R.drawable.a70,
        R.drawable.a71, R.drawable.a72
        , R.drawable.a73, R.drawable.a74, R.drawable.a75
        , R.drawable.a76, R.drawable.a77, R.drawable.a78
        , R.drawable.a79, R.drawable.a80, R.drawable.a81
        , R.drawable.a82, R.drawable.a83, R.drawable.a84, R.drawable.a85, R.drawable.a86, R.drawable.a87

        , R.drawable.a88,
        R.drawable.a89, R.drawable.a90
        , R.drawable.a91, R.drawable.a93
        , R.drawable.a94, R.drawable.a95, R.drawable.a96
        , R.drawable.a97, R.drawable.a98, R.drawable.a99

    };

public int playstop = 0;

private Button extisaw;
private ImagePagerAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
public void onCreate(Bundle ww) {
    super.onCreate(ww);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saw);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raj);
    show1();
    show2();
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (playstop == 0) {
                    MediaHandler(mp, 1);
                    mp.start();
                    playstop = 1;

                } else {
                    MediaHandler(mp, 2);
                    mp.pause();
                    playstop = 0;
                }
            }
        });
}

private void show2()
{
    // TODO: Implement this method

    this.extisaw =
        (Button)this.findViewById
    (R.id.about);
    this.extisaw.setOnClickListener
    (new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
    });



}

public void MediaHandler
(MediaPlayer mp, int e) {
    if (e == 1) {
        mp.start();
    } else {
        mp.pause();
    }
}


private void saveImageIntoSdcard(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File filename = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String destination;

    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        destination ="/DESTINATIONFOLDER NAME/";
  File sdCardDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),destination);
    filename = new File(sdCardDirectory, System.currentTimeMillis()+"image.jpg");



                out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                        out);


                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(),
                        filename.getName(), filename.getName());


        }
 catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void show1() {
     viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
     adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            int selectedImage=mImages[position];
            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),selectedImage);
            saveImageIntoSdcard(largeIcon);
        }
    });
}

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = DemoActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
            R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank u . I copy the code and paste it . but when I click in the button there is nothing happen…..

Comment: I have add the promision  to the mainfest and there is no wrong on the code. Please try the code to find where is the problem.  Why it doesnt save the image

Comment: Where the image must be saved in the sd crd?  I search in the sdcard and I dont found any image has been saved

Comment: First u need to add premission in manifest for writeExternal directory and find destintionfolder name .all images stored in this folder

Comment: I add this to mainfest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Is there any second permision to add?

Comment: just to click up arrow on post

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add the permission to the manifest for accessing to the external storage:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then you must get the bitmap of the desired image and create a file in the external storage:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File imageFile = new File(sdCardDirectory, "image.png");
```

Finally write the bitmap into the file:

```
FileOutputStream outStream;
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
        outStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        outStream.close();
    }
```

You can introduce a boolean for checking if the process of writting is properly completed.

Comment: I dont understand u ,, can u explain more…  or give me an example

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:-


int position = viewPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
String imagePath= list.get(position);
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputSteam(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath))));
    File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File imageFile = new File(sdCardDirectory, "image.png");
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: It doesnt work please give me another code or a example project for saving image

Answer (score 0):

**try this may this help you.**

```
    private void saveImageIntoSdcard(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File filename = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String destination;

    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        destination ="/DESTINATIONFOLDER NAME/";

        new File(path + destination).mkdirs();

        filename = new File(path + destination + ".jpg");
                out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                bitmapReceipt.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                        out);
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity()
                        .getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(),
                        filename.getName(), filename.getName());


        }
 catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is problems…  please can u add this code to my mainactivity code???  My code is in the link to mediafire…  I  am waiting u

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/error.php?errno=399&quickkey=v54nwyqbqcm10y1b5myjj55vje5lotb

Comment: I post my code please see it and add to it button to save the current image in view pager

Answer (score 0):

```
I have edit your code try this.


private void saveImageIntoSdcard(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File filename = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String destination;

    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        destination ="/DESTINATIONFOLDER NAME/";
  File sdCardDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),destination);
    filename = new File(sdCardDirectory, System.currentTimeMillis()+"image.jpg");



                out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                        out);


                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity()
                        .getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(),
                        filename.getName(), filename.getName());


        }
 catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the bitmap you pass is not null

Comment: Thank u but I am new in java and I want u to put this code to my demoavtivity.java and give it to me… .please I wait u

Comment: Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {