# Probleme saving a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, save, drawable, internal-storage

When I save a bitmap with this function, I get an unreadable file, bigger than the original image(using Root explorer on my phone) what is wrong?
The bitmap is set by the user using the stock image picker.

Here is the call:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
saveToInternalSorage(bitmap);
```

Here the saveToInternalSorage method (from here [Saving and Reading Bitmaps/Images from Internal memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android) )

```
 private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){

    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    String filename = randomString();
    System.out.println(filename);
    File mypath=new File(directory,filename);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: What is randomString() returning ?

Comment: @AnoopM it returns a String with some random char for an unique image name

Comment: Give me an example file name it returns..

Comment: @AnoopM  here the code and one example : psE@B.h;}7

        public static String randomString() {
        Random generator = new Random();
        StringBuilder randomStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        char tempChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            tempChar = (char) (generator.nextInt(96) + 32);
            randomStringBuilder.append(tempChar);
        }
        return randomStringBuilder.toString();
    }

Comment: What is the image name showing in storage after saving ?

Comment: @AnoopM i assume that the image dont need to have the extension or the system to know that its an image, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84077/discussion-between-gokh-and-anoop-m).