# How to get address from gallery in android

Tags: android, inputstream, image-gallery

I write this code and my code choose one picture from gallery and get data from it but I dont konw how to get image address from Inputstrem or data and store it?

```
public void loadPic()
{
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
}

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        try {
            Uri selectedImage=data.getData();
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            listItems.add(inputStream.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need the path of the image selected from Gallery? You can do whatever you want with the `InputStream` you get from the Intent in the `onActivityResult` callback.

Comment: use BitmapFactory to get bitmap, accordinly
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

Comment: really!! Can I copy it in another place

Comment: but I need its name

Comment: Name of the image you choose from Gallery?

Comment: yes .that image I choose

Comment: ok posted code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read filename name like below, use it accordingly.

```
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            File f = new File(picturePath);
            String imageName = f.getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you can't get a file from the picture you choose.
It's because the choosen one came from Google+, Drive, Dropbox or any other provider.

The best solution is to ask the system to pick a content via [Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) and get the result with a content provider.

```
public void pickImage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  intent.setType("image/*");
  startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            //Display an error
            return;
        }
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
        //Now you can do whatever you want with your inpustream, save it as file, upload to a server, decode a bitmap...
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer have problem at "compiler " said we havent this class and said change to "context" but when do it show this error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContentResolver() from the type Context"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can get the image like this:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
```

Once you have the Bitmap, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674787/6570665) on how to store it.

EDIT: Try this

```
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Taken from [here](http://paragchauhan2010.blogspot.com/2012/05/choose-image-from-gallary-and-display.html).

Comment: I need to save address for next time what about this?

Comment: Check edit @Amir133. Let me know if that doesn't work or if you need more help.