# Saving an image from ImageView into internal storage

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, internal-storage

I have created an ImageView and I can see the preview of the camera and load the captured image into the ImageView and I wanted to store the image into a directory in my internal memory. I have referred many posts and tried but I couldn't find my image in my internal memory.

This is the code I have used:

```java
package com.example.shravan.camera;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "abc";

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE =1 ;
    ImageView iv;
    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myB);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myIV);
        //disable the button if the user has no camera
        if (!hasCamera()) {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasCamera() {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    //on click event handler that launches the camera
    public void launchCamera(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageUri=data.getData();
            iv.setImageURI(imageUri);;
        }
    }

    public void SaveFile(View v) {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

        print("Creating cw");
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(this.getApplicationContext());
        print("Creating dir");
        File directory = cw.getDir("ImagesDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        print("Created dir" + directory);
        File mypath = new File(directory,"myImagesDGS.jpg");
        print("path is" + mypath);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            print("creating fos");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            print("Compressing bitmap");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
                print("fos closed");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void print(String str){
        Log.d(TAG, str);
    }

}
```

I have made many log messages to debug and I got one path which I couldn't find in my phone.

This is the logcat:

> 08-07 21:47:37.089 11030-11030/com.example.shravan.camera D/abc:
>       Creating cw 08-07
>
> 21:47:37.089 11030-11030/com.example.shravan.camera
>       D/abc: Creating dir 08-07
>
> 21:47:37.099
>       11030-11030/com.example.shravan.camera D/abc: Created
>       dir/data/user/0/com.example.shravan.camera/app_ImagesDir 08-07
>
> 21:47:37.099 11030-11030/com.example.shravan.camera D/abc: path
>       is/data/user/0/com.example.shravan.camera/app_ImagesDir/myImagesDGS.jpg
>
> 08-07 21:47:37.099 11030-11030/com.example.shravan.camera D/abc:
>       creating fos
>
> 08-07 21:47:37.099 11030-11030/com.example.shravan.camera
>       D/abc: Compressing bitmap
>
> 08-07 21:47:42.589
>       11030-11030/com.example.shravan.camera D/abc: fos closed

Is there anything I need to check and I should change? Please help!

Comment: ITs in /data/user/0/com.example.shravan.camera/app_ImagesDir/myImagesDGS.jpg.  But you need root access to get at private app files.

Comment: Your app saved a file in an app specific private directory. Only your app has access (no need for root)). Not other apps like file explorers which you used to find the file.

Comment: @greenapps How can I find it on file explorer then?

Comment: @GabeSechan How can I access it from other apps? What modifications do I need to make?

Comment: As said you can not find it with a file explorer. So don't save your file in internal memory but in external.

Comment: My device doesn't have an external storage. That's the problem! What should I do now in this case to create a separate folder in my internal memory and then store my images in that directory?

Comment: All devices have internal and external storage. It is unclear where you are talking about.  If you put a micro SD card in it then that is considered removable storage.

Comment: Ya. My device doesn't have support for a micro SD. All it has is internal storage. So, that's the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it working!

I used this code to create a directory in my file storage and then store the image:

```java
FileOutputStream outStream = null;

// Write to SD Card
try {
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
    dir.mkdirs();

    String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
    File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

    outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

    refreshGallery(outFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    print("FNF");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

}
```

My permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Finally, the most important thing:

Go to Device Settings>Device>Applications>Application Manager>"your app">Permissions>Enable Storage permission!

Comment: I've seen many suggestions but this one worked for me because of the important final step haha, most were missing this step so thanks

Comment: No worries mate

Comment: describing top to bottom, thanks, just send a parameter Bitmap bitmap,  to the method, excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The location your current images are saving, cannot be accessed by an other application.It's better to save them in a accessible location.try like this..

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
 try {
           String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
           File file = new File(root + "/YourDirectory/myImagesDGS.jpg");
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

then you can retrieve your saved images like this..

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File file = new File(root + "/YourDirectory/myImagesDGS.jpg");    
Bitmap bmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: `The location your current images are saving, cannot be accessed`. Of course you can. If you can write to files there you can read them too. Please rephrase what you mean.

Comment: I have tried your code and it gave me a file not found exception! What am I missing?

Comment: But my device doesn't have external storage! How to create a directory in internal storage? @greenapps

Comment: @ShravanDG actually you does...the one you can access(Internal Storage) is referred as external storage here..

Comment: Where will the images be saved (the directory of the app or YourDirectory) in internal memory? I didn't find anything in either of these folders!

Comment: @ShravanDG you'll find a directory called "yourdirectory" in your storage...that is where the file is being stored

Comment: @Sandaruwan I cannot create the directory and save the image. I have been trying it in several ways. Can you please help?

Comment: @ShravanDG are there any execeptions thrown....can you please check where the code breaks using `Log.e()` or something

Comment: I am getting a FileNotFound exception! Don't know why! What am I missing?

Comment: can you check weather the file is properly stored or not in the storage...using a file manager tool or something..

Comment: That is the problem. I have checked it! It is not being stored!

Comment: It is stored in some random location /data/user/0/com.example.shravan.asbdbsadbsabcxscsa/app_mydir/myfile which I cant find. By default I can ses the image in DCIM folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is saving from this path `/data/user/0/com.example.shravan.camera/app_ImagesDir/myImagesDGS.jpg`
but your are not access.try this code for iamge reading.Call this method into onCreate this method is return you bitmap.

```
 Bitmap mBitmap= getImageBitmap(this,"myImagesDGS","jpg");

   if(mBitmap !=null){

yourImageView.setBitmap(mBitmap);

}else{

Log.d("MainActivity","Image is not found");
}
```

It is sepread method

```
     public Bitmap getImageBitmap(Context context,String name,String extension){
        name=name+"."+extension;  
        try{ 
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(name);
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                fis.close();
                return b;
            } 
            catch(Exception e){
            } 
            return null; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. I modified my code to fit the code your provide. I did not test it. I temporary store the photo taken into a file with time stamp, then use the filename to retrieve the file. Hope it helps

```
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
public void launchCamera(View v)
{
    //Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    //startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                            "tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (mImageCaptureUri!=null){
//Do whatever you want with the uri
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that code, you will be ended to store your file to your private application data. **You can't access that data with other applications except your application itself without root access**. You can get the public image directory by using this code instead when declaring the file path if you want your image file can be accessed by other applications.

```
File albumF;
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    albumF = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
} else {
    albumF = context.getFilesDir();
}
```

If you need to make your sub directory inside public gallery directory, you can change the code above like this:

```
File albumF;
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    albumF = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), YOUR_SUB_DIRECTORY_STRING);
} else {
    albumF = new File(context.getFilesDir(), YOUR_SUB_DIRECTORY_STRING);
}
```

You might be need to add this code to create that album directory

```
if (!albumF.exists()) {
    albumF.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but still can't find my image directory or image in gallery! It just gets added to my default camera  folder. Please help

Comment: @ShravanDG yes, nothing wrong with the code, because it should work like that. I will add a code to make your subfolder inside the public gallery folder

Comment: I have just tried the code and my app is stopping unfortunately. Can you plese look into this? 

my code: (I am saving the image on button click)

Comment: //after converting image to bitmap then
        File albumF;
   if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            albumF = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyDir");
        }
        else
        {
            albumF = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "MyDir");
        }
            albumF.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(albumF, "a.jpg");
            FileOutputStream fout =  new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fout);
    }

Comment: @ShravanDG can you show the stack trace of the error?

Comment: I got this: E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer, 
E/System: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                               at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                               at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub$Proxy.stopWatchingMode(IAppOpsService.java:431)
                                               at android.media.SoundPool.release(SoundPool.java:195)
                                               at android...

Comment: Hendra Wijaya Djiono- I debugged it! The app is crashing at this part:
albumF.mkdirs();
   File file = new File(albumF, FILENAME + CurrentDateAndTime + ".jpg");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
What shoud I do? (error while creating the fout and getting a FileNotFound exception!) Help..

Comment: Try to check if the file exist first. If not exist, just create the file. if(!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ImageSaver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35827955/1129332). It's a synchronous way to save and load images from internal and external storage.

### Usage

- To save:

  ```
  new ImageSaver(context).
          setFileName("myImage.png").
          setDirectoryName("images").
          setExternal(true).
          save(bitmap);
  ```
- To load:

  ```
  Bitmap bitmap = new ImageSaver(context).
          setFileName("myImage.png").
          setDirectoryName("images").
          setExternal(true).
          load();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @Shravan DG gives error for me. I have modified his code little bit and it works without errors.

```
 private void downloadQR()
{
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    
    try {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "QRCode_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "PARENT_DIR)/CHILD_DIR/");
        storageDir.mkdirs();

        File outFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) qrCode.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Chill Pill :)