# Download file from base64 url in android webview

Tags: java, android, webview, download, base64

I am writing a webview app in which i can download files from (html  tag) urls to device. I can download files like png/jpg/pdf etc, but when url is a base64 string value i don't know how to download it. Can someone help me to achieve that?

For example, when the below html link clicked file ***abc.png*** can be downloaded easily

```
<a href="http://web.com/abc.png" download >Download</a>
```

But when url is base64 like below, webview can't download the "file":

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." download>Download</a>
```

Comment: @DimaKozhevin no, it is not same question. I don't want to load image to webview, i want to convert base64 to file and save it to device

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I could manage to save base64 encoded data as a file. So, the basic short answer to my question was decoding encoded data to bytes and writing it to a file like this:

> ```
> String base64EncodedString = encodedDataUrl.substring(encodedDataUrl.indexOf(",") + 1);
> byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(base64EncodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
> OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
> os.write(decodedBytes);
> os.close();
> ```

Just for reference for others who may come up with the same question I am adding my final code below. Inside `onCreate()` method i am handling file downloads like this:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                long contentLength) {

        if (url.startsWith("data:")) {  //when url is base64 encoded data
            String path = createAndSaveFileFromBase64Url(url);
            return;
        }

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.msg_downloading));
        String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);
        request.setTitle(filename);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.msg_downloading, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

And `createAndSaveFileFromBase64Url()` method which deals with base64 encoded data looks like this:

```
public String createAndSaveFileFromBase64Url(String url) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        String filetype = url.substring(url.indexOf("/") + 1, url.indexOf(";"));
        String filename = System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + filetype;
        File file = new File(path, filename);
        try {
            if(!path.exists())
                path.mkdirs();
            if(!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();

            String base64EncodedString = url.substring(url.indexOf(",") + 1);
            byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(base64EncodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            os.write(decodedBytes);
            os.close();

            //Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is immediately available to the user.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });

            //Set notification after download complete and add "click to view" action to that
            String mimetype = url.substring(url.indexOf(":") + 1, url.indexOf("/"));
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), (mimetype + "/*"));
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                                        .setContentText(getString(R.string.msg_file_downloaded))
                                                        .setContentTitle(filename)
                                                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                                                        .build();

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            int notificationId = 85851;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.error_downloading, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return file.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Your code gives me the following error, can you help me with this?:
`android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/1548198938835.png exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1799)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2346)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8965)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:8926)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:340)`

Comment: @LeninMeza this maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 1.8, you can try with

```
     import java.util.Base64;

     public class DecodeBase64 {

     public static void main(String []args){
        String encodedUrl = "aHR0cHM6Ly9zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbS9xdWVzdGlvbnMvNDY1NzkyMzcvZG93bmxvYWQtZmlsZS1mcm9tLWJhc2U2NC11cmwtaW4tYW5kcm9pZC13ZWJ2aWV3LzQ2NTc5MzE0";
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encodedUrl);
        String result = new String(decodedBytes);
        System.out.println(result);
     }
}
```

output should be:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579237/download-file-from-base64-url-in-android-webview/46579314`

Comment: Thanks, but what should i do after i decoded base64 and created a bitmap ?

Comment: you need to convert your byte array to String, I modified the snippet above

Comment: must add the getUrlDecoder() to get a URL and filename safe decoder

Comment: it is not image url encoded, it is the file itself encoded to base64. Basically a file generated dynamically using javascript in website and created file's base64 code is written to html <a> tag's href and then clicked, which starts file download.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert this base64 string to bitmap image format than  try to download that.

you can convert your string like this.

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
{
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, Base64.DEFAULT); 


    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

it will return bitmap of your base64.

Comment: Ok, after i created bitmap, what i should do with that ?

Comment: you can set this bitmap in any hidden imageview .like this 

imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

after that . you can download that easily . as you downloaded before

Comment: Sorry, i still didn't get that. For other files there is an html tag like: <a download href="image.png" >download</a> and basically clicking on it will download it

Comment: As you mentioned in your question  you can download file from html tag . now whats the matter?

Comment: If url contains file path/name i can download it, but if the url is base64 i can't. it is that simple

Comment: After following processes i mentioned you need to visit this.. 

'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820673/saving-an-image-from-imageview-into-internal-storage'