# Saving image from ImageView to storage

Tags: android, imageview, storage

I followed the answers of [Saving an image from ImageView into internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820673/saving-an-image-from-imageview-into-internal-storage) but I still can't save anything.. My code is here :

```
 public void buttonPickImage(View view) {

        FileOutputStream fos;

        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        Random rng = new Random();
        int n = rng.nextInt(1000);




        try {

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/BAC");
            bool = dir.mkdir();

            File file = new File(dir, "BAC_"+n+".jpg");


            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image sauvegardée"+bool,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }catch (java.io.IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IOException: " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

With this method I get the IOExeception with messae : `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/BAC/BAC_396.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

I also tried this to save it to internal storage but its not working for me :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-write-an-image-file-in-internal-storage-in-android
With this method, program runs but boolean mkdir gives me false.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: `dir.mkdir();` Only call mkdir if the directory does not exist yet. And if you fo check the return value. If it returns false display a toast to inform the user. And return. Dont continue as that makes no sense if the directory does not exist. Please try and then adapt your code here too.

Comment: You did not tell which toast is displayed. So how would we know?

Comment: `"not working"`. That should be `"IOException: " + e.getMessage()` to inform the user better.

Comment: You also did not post relevant lines from the logcat. You probably have an IOException but did not inform us.

Comment: `to internal storage but its not working for me` Well what happened instead? What are the errors?

Comment: @blackapps I edit my qtn with the error message. Toast displayed is "not working". I know the text is not accurate but it was for testing on my computer, not for users

Comment: When I try the internal storage solution, I get the first toast (successful) and no error, but nthing is saved in my storage

Comment: It is time you do all the things suggested for mkdir. Pretty strange you did not even react to my first comment.

Comment: `text is not accurate but it was for testing on my computer, not for users ` No good. If you do not display e.getMessage() you know nothing.

Comment: `... I get the first toast (successful) and no error, but nthing is saved in my storage ` How did you check that?

Comment: I checked the run tab and logcat. I updated my post again to show you what happens with mkdir and egetMessages for both cases

Comment: `I checked the run tab and logcat.` ?? To find a file? Further you did change noting concerning mkdir() and e.getMessage(). You did not adapt your code here.

Comment: `With this method, program runs but boolean mkdir gives me false.` There is no mkdir used in that example.

Comment: No, to find an error. I checked the file in the storage of device. Sorry I updated with mkddir use

Comment: `bool = dir.mkdir();` ????????

Comment: I did this to get the boolean value of mkdir as you told me in the first reponse. It's just a variable to be displayed in toast

Comment: No it is not just a variable to be displayed in a toast. Where do you check its value? You should do that immediately on the following line. And then display a toast if false and return. I said that before. You now blindly continue. I told you all yesterday and you still did not adapt your code. Sigh..  Further you now also did not tell us if it was false or true. And.. i also told you to only call mkdir if the directory does not exist yet. That you did not implement either.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working using **Media Store** instead of getExternalStorageDirectory as

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
> To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

MediaStore is also useful as it allows you to get the image in your android gallery app.

So my solution is :

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "any_picture_name");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "test");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "test Image taken");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        OutputStream outstream;
        try {
            outstream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, outstream);
            outstream.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Still thank you @blackapps for explaining me some basics things about the IOexception, mkdir and toasts. It'll be useful anyway.