# Storing Image from ImageView to Internal Storage

Tags: android

This is the code. The application is installed successfully but in `insertImage` `null` is being stored always. i.e, the image is not getting stored in internal storage and always showing `Drawing not saved!`

```
final AlertDialog.Builder saveDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.savebtn) {


                saveDialog.setTitle("Save Drawing");
                saveDialog.setMessage("Save drawing to Gallery");
                saveDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        drawableView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        String insertImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), drawableView.getDrawingCache(), UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");
                        if (insertImage!= null) {
                            Toast savedtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drawing Saved to gallery!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            savedtoast.show();
                        } else {
                            Toast unsaved = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Drawing not saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            unsaved.show();
                        }
                        drawableView.destroyDrawingCache();
                    }
                });
                saveDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
                saveDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help me out to recognize the problem.

Comment: please explain your problem in detail and be specific so that others can understand your problem, read your code, and help you.

Comment: I edited my query, please have a look now.

Comment: can you please check or debug ```drawableView.getDrawingCache()```. this method is deprecated in API 28. check this is providing you the correct drawable. I think debugging that line with android studio debugger can help you. also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674787/5339146 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15662384/5339146 https://stackoverflow.com/a/38903796/5339146 for your understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving an image from ImageView into internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820673/saving-an-image-from-imageview-into-internal-storage)

Comment: https://appetize.io/app/4eet4ezthk0va9zg5dcqv8wg74?device=nexus5&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=8.1

Comment: this is my app. I want that when I click on save button, the image will save to gallery. But w.r.t above code in String insertImage always null stores. I hope you got it now what I am trying to say.