# Bitmapfactory.decodeStream throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

I am trying to save and retrieve a Bitmap from internal storage but everytime I try to load bitmap, BitMapFactory throws Exception:

```
BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.graphics.Bitmap@b35e414: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried nearly all solutions given by similar threads on this website, but none worked for me. 
And this exception is thrown 4 times, though I am reading only one image.How?

And this is the code I am using to save and retrieve images from storage.

```
public static void saveFile(Context context, Bitmap b, String picName) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(picName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("store DRV image", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Context context, String picName) {
    Bitmap b = null;
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(picName);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        fis.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("get stored DRV image", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

I got this code from a thread on this website, and all comments were good. But its not working for me. I have added permissions in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Lastly, I am using random generated UIDs as filename. The UIDs are generated using Firebase SDK. So the UID may contain numbers or other characters like
`XXgKbRiS5ogQz1euqiyRsC1ggBS2`. So is this a wrong way to name a file? and hence exception is thrown?

Comment: Please share the picName value or the code where it is initialize

Comment: @AnujJPandey Picname is `XXgKbRiS5ogQz1euqiyRsC1ggBS2` and I even tried using `myImage` and `myImage.png`. but exception is thrown.

Comment: which android os are you using?

Comment: @JdPrajapati I am testing on Android 6.01 Marshmallow.

Comment: did u add runtime permissions?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 No, is it needed for storage too? I thought it is required only for location.

Comment: check my add answer, you need to add user permission

Comment: @MrunalAhirrao there should be complete path of file instead of only file name.

Comment: @AnujJPandey but the code I am using don't return any path so which path should I add?

Comment: Create some directory and provide entire path while saving the image, if you are using any sdk to save file then there will some method to set file path

Comment: @Same code which I have written in question `saveFile ` and `loadBitmap`

Comment: @AnujJPandey so using names like `XXgKbRiS5ogQz1euqiyRsC1ggBS2` would do? if I use a path?

Comment: @AnujJPandey Now I am using this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android It gives absolute path but still the same exception is thrown!

Comment: use runtime permission and also check it in Settings/apps/YOURAPP/permissions

Comment: @AnujJPandey permissions are granted. And by modifying your code I think I am able to save the image because I got path in Log. But while fetching some error is taking place.

Comment: what error please paste message

Comment: @AnujJPandey there was no log for that error. But I was filling  a bitmap ArrayList using your code and it was null so I was saying there was error. But now again `BitmapFactory FileNotFoundException` has occurred. Its quiet hard to play with images on Android it seems!

Comment: please make sure that you are decoding the same file you saved ....

Answer (score 1):

You need to add user permission above 6.0:

```
Add library:
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'

private String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, galleryPermissions)) {
        pickImageFromGallery();
    } else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Access for storage",
                101, galleryPermissions);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in onCreate() of your Activity:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
```

catch the result in same activity using:

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 0: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //call your method
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
 }
```

Learn more about Runtime Permission from [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: The runtime permission dialog is not opening. And I have requested permission in onCreate as you suggested.

Comment: what is your target sdk in gradle?

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 23

Comment: clear your app data and clean install the apk and run the code...the dialog should display

Comment: exception is thrown in `saveFile` or `loadBitmap` ?

Comment: Ok I will do it. And Android Studio shows error Cannot resolve symbol for this `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` so I used `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` so is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137195/discussion-between-rafsanahmad007-and-mrunal-ahirrao).

Comment: exception is thrown in loadBitmap

Answer (score 0):

//Make sure permission are granted
    //For saving

```
 File file=saveFile(contex,bitmap,picName);
    //For fetching
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), picName);
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath())

 /**
     * @param context
     * @param b
     * @param picName
     */
    public static File saveFile(Context context, Bitmap b, String picName) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "My Images");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(dir, picName);
        try {
            fos = context.openFileOutput(file.getPath(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("store DRV image", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: I will try using with this. So while fetching, there is no need to add "MyImages" in file path?

Comment: Using this code while saving getting `IllegalArgumentException contains path separator` error.