# Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I use next code to play with a temporary SQLite table:

```
public class DBHelperForTemp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static String DB_NAME = "tempdb";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 3;

public DBHelperForTemp(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE tbl ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, image BLOB )";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean add_Temp_Values(String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("image", image);

    long result = db.insert("tbl", null, contentValues);

    return result != -1;
}


public Cursor get_Data(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}


public void ClearData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from tbl");
}

}
```

save data to temp:

```
private void  doTemp(){
    final Bitmap photo = ((BitmapDrawable) mPhotoImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    boolean insertData = mDBTemp.add_Temp_POI_Values(mNameEditText.getText().toString(),
           Utils.imageToByteArray(photo) );
    if (insertData){
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.fb_success, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.fb_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finish();
}
```

and try to read from temp and send to firebase with:

```
private void onSubmit(){
    final DBHelperForTemp mDBTemp = new DBHelperForTemp(this);
    final Cursor data = mDBTemp.get_Data();
    if (data != null && data.getCount() != 0 && data.moveToFirst()){
        for (int i = 0; i < data.getCount(); i++) {
            final String name = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("name"));
            final byte[] byteArray = data.getBlob(data.getColumnIndex("image"));
            final Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0 , byteArray.length);
.........
```

I get next error code when try to use it:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                         at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                         at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:451)
                                                                                         at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                         at com.test.test.activities.ActivityMain.onSubmit
```

What is interesting is that code work if I don't have an image in temporary table. If have an image the app crash but there where try to read the name string and not image.

Anyone can help me to detect problem?

data.getCount() return 1. data.getColumnIndex("name") return 0. data.getString(0) return Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception. Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the image you stored is too big, CursorWindow has a maximum size of 2048Kb per row

Comment: Yes. Have 8Mb. Can I get somehow bigger images from a SQLite database?

Comment: Save them in internal storage instead of using the database for image blob. You can find a sample here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android