# How to Save Image in Internal Storage and show image in imageView in another acitivity

Tags: android, android-imageview

*How to Save Image in Internal Storage and show image in imageView in another acitivity ,please tell me how to save that image in internal storage because many phones have only internal storage not sd card*

## this is my first acitivity

```
 //camera
    camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.takePic);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File pictureDirectory=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String pictureName=getPictureName();
            File imageFile=new File(pictureDirectory,pictureName);
             pictureUri=Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

 private String getPictureName() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    String timestamp=sdf.format(new Date());
    return "Plane place image"+timestamp+".jpg";

}

  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==RESULT_OK){
        if (resultCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            pictureUri = data.getData();
            if (pictureUri!=null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, PictureActivity.class);
                intent.setData(pictureUri);
                intent.putExtra("imgUrl", pictureUri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## this is my second activity

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {
        Log.e("ashish", bundle.getString("imgUrl") + "");
         path = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imgUrl"));

    }

    ImageView selfiiii = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mySelfie);
    selfiiii.setImageURI(path);
```

Comment: what is a problem with your code?

Comment: what is exact issue that you are facing..

Comment: Learn about Shard Preference it's help you to store a data or retrieve also https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Save the Image in storage and then load the image wherever you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko after capture image and after save image when i back from camera then i come in first activity(present activity) not going to second activity it mean uri getting null.  so whats solution

Comment: ok, for camera should specify the output, where it should put a captured image like this: `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);` After in onActivityResult you can pass `outputFileUri` to second activity

Comment: sir please post answer after edit in my code properly please @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: I don't have time for that unfortunately. I think you can do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i am store image in emulator internal storage used below code...

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
     // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
   // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
          fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: check your onActivity Result method your data give null value.

Comment: i know my data give null value thats why i asked this questions so please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

make changes in opencamera method like used below code...

```
    private void OpenCamera(){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap thumbnail = null;

    if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
                thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DbInsert.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", thumbnail);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

    }
}
```

second Activity...

```
        Bitmap bitmap  = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("name");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```