# How to save a URI as a jpg file to a custom folder on the internal storage?

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

I have a URI that contains **"0/data/app/data/croppedimage.jpg"** and I want to save that in internal storage with the new folder with my file name like **"/storage/emulated/0/myfolder/myimage.jpg"** from `onActivity` result.

**The code is given below,**

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();}}
```

I have tried with FileOutputStream but myImage file crashes or broken.

code below,

```
 File folderPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/OCR");

            if (!folderPath.exists()) {
                if (folderPath.mkdir()) ; //directory is created;
            } else {
                File photo = new File("/storage/emulated/0/myfolder/myimage.jpg");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(photo);
                    fileOutputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(resultUri.toString()));
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674787/2919483

Comment: which exceptions do you get?

Comment: my task is that uri has different path and I want to save it in different path.

Comment: A few things I can see: **(a)** you _either_ create the `folderPath` directory if it doesn't exist, _or_ you try to write a file – not both! **(b)** You ignore `folderPath` and use a hard-coded path for the file you appear to be trying to save to. **(c)** As far as I can see, all you are writing to that file is the result of trying to parse the URI as a number ... you never actually seem to _read_ from the URI.

Comment: see my new answer and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using image crop library. In this case you can use FileProviders concept like this

> You should append your package name to `.fileprovider` like com.yourpackagename.fileprovider

add this to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.yourpackagename.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
</provider>
```

inside res folder create `xml` sub folder and inside this sub folder add this file

`provider_path.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
</paths>
```

add this as global variable inside your activity

`private static final String CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER = "com.yourpackage.name.fileprovider";`

And then change your `startCropImageActivity()` method like this

```
    private void startCropImageActivity(Uri imageUri)
{
    File file = null;
    try
    {
        file = createImageFile();
        Uri mUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                CAPTURE_IMAGE_FILE_PROVIDER, file);
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setMultiTouchEnabled(true)
                .setAllowFlipping(false)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .setRequestedSize(350, 350)
                .setMinCropResultSize(350, 350)
                .setMaxCropResultSize(800, 800)
                .setOutputCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
                .setOutputCompressQuality(90)
                .setOutputUri(mUri)
                .start(this);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "MYAPPNAME-" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "YourAppFolder");
    File storageDir = new File(mediaStorageDir + "/Profile_Images");
    if (!storageDir.exists())
    {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
    return image;
}
```

and finally

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    // handle result of pick image chooser
    if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);

        // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage.
        if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(this, imageUri))
        {
            // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
            mCropImageUri = imageUri;
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            // no permissions required or already grunted, can start crop image activity
            startCropImageActivity(imageUri);
        }
    }

    // handle result of CropImageActivity
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            profileImageFilepath = result.getUri().getPath();
            Log.d("cropImageUri", result.getUri().getPath());
            new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Photo Selected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Photo Selection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

take permissions for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This solution will save your croped image to `/storage/emulated/0/yourfolder/yourimage.jpg`