# What is the best way to store images locally in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create an offline app in which the user can add images with image detail. I want to as that what is the best way to store image offline?

Should I use SQLite blob format, SQLite base64 encoded String or should I store it in internal storage or Should I store It in shared Preference. Please help me, If you know any other way then please mention it.

Comment: `"Should I use SQLite blob format, SQLite base64 encoded String or should I store it in internal storage"` the last option is in most cases the best

Answer (score 1):

Internal storage is best of all. 
if you want to keep it private ,change format of image and then save 
otherwise save as it is

Answer (score 0):

To save image locally use below code :

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
     // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
   // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
          fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674787/830988