# How to transfer image to another activity

Tags: java, android

I have two activity, First with button, which calls void openCamera, and second, where I need to get bitmap.
I have two questions: 
1. Which line of code is saving pictures? 
2. How I can take a bitmap from OnActivityResult and get it in another activity?

```
private void openCamera() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Taking pic from the Camera");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        SelectedImage.setImageURI(image_uri);
        try {
            Bitmap ImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), image_uri);
            detectImage(ImageBitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about passing it through `Bundle` (docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

I think, you should save the image in internal storage of your app and then load it in your second activity.
Here are the answers explaining how to do that: [Saving and Reading Bitmaps/Images from Internal memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Pass image uri as string along with activity intent

```
mIntent.putExtra("image", image_url.toString());
```

In the receiving activity get the uri and move your code to generate bitmap there.

```
String image_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
//your code to get bitmap
```