# Kotlin: saving the image contained in a imageview

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in kotlin and in android studio and I need your help !
I do not understand how to save the image from an imageview. I tried with intend but it does not work.

Here is the imageview:

```
private lateinit var resultImageView: ImageView
```

This is how I set the image inside the imageview:

```
private fun setImageView(imageView: ImageView, image: Bitmap) {
    Glide.with(baseContext)
      .load(image)
      .override(512, 512)
      .fitCenter()
      .into(imageView)
  }
```

What can I change to save it into the internal storage? Should I create a new function or can I do it into the setImageView?

I am working with android 11 and kotlin 1.4.10

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving and Reading Bitmaps/Images from Internal memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android)